# Cannot use Cabal in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, haskell, ubuntu, cabal

I try to perfom

```
$ cabal --version
```

but it says cabal is not installed. You can install it by typing sudo apt-get install cabal-install. But when I do so, it says: cabal-install is already the newest version.
However, I cannot use it. Why?

Comment: Go to `/usr/bin` and see if `cabal` executable is present.

Comment: no, it is not.. what can I do to be there since it says is already installed?

Comment: Try 'dpkg -L cabal-install', which will show where the package's files are, if it is installed.

Comment: Try and see if it is present in some other location: `find / -name cabal`

Comment: dpkg -L cabal-install says it is installed in /usr/bin but there is no folder or file named cabal there

Comment: @Steffi Do `sudo apt-get purge cabal-install` and then try reinstalling again.

Comment: @Sibi can you post your comments as an answer, so that it can be accepted and this question will be marked as closed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that your package isn't properly installed. So remove it cleanly using this command:

`sudo apt-get purge cabal-install`

And once this is over, re-install it again using the familiar command:

`sudo apt-get install cabal-install`